# Unity3D WebRequest URL doesn't work when I add some parameter to URL string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrequest, unitywebrequest

I am doing basic game project for my college.
I have a backend project and the project's get or post methods work correctly on postman or any browser.
On the Unity side,
I created 2 Inputfields (username, password)
and created 1 Button (Login)

I create a c# script and define URL string and made webrequest with an IEnumerator and then StartCoroutine in the start method. This way it works fine

```
private string URL = "https://localhost:44310/api/users/getbyaccount?username=blablabla&&password=blablabla";

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetResult());
}


IEnumerator GetResult()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(URL))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {

            string message;
            message = request.downloadHandler.text;

            messageBoxContainer.gameObject.SetActive(true); 
            messageBoxText.text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to create string URL with username and password come from inputfields. So, I created a button and wrote a method when click add the parameters(username and password) to URL string. But doesn't work.

```
public Image messageBoxContainer;

public TMP_Text _userName;
public TMP_Text _password;

public TextMeshProUGUI messageBoxText;


private string URL;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   // StartCoroutine(GetResult());
}


IEnumerator GetResult()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(URL))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {

            string message;
            message = request.downloadHandler.text;

            messageBoxContainer.gameObject.SetActive(true); 
            messageBoxText.text += message;
        }
    }
}


public void CreateUrl()
{
   
    URL ="https://localhost:44310/api/users/getbyaccount?username=" + _userName.text + "&&password=" + _password.text;

    messageBoxText.text = URL;

    StartCoroutine(GetResult());
}
```

How can I add the parameters to URL string?

Comment: what web error do you get, what is your weburl looking like in the second one? what has your server received?

Comment: You have a double `&&` in your URL. That may make it invalid. Try fixing that. Also I wouldn't pass a username and password as query string parameters. They're more likely to be logged in access logs, etc.

Comment: @BugFinder Actually, there is no system error. If I write the string with the correct username and password, the link works on postman or browsers. The result is success and the link brought to me my result object. 
On the unity side, If I write the same link as one-piece, it works correctly again and it brings the expected data. But If I add username and password to string on runtime it brings to me my errorrdataresult. I come my successdataresult. Username and password are correctly or wrongly it doesn’t matter. Always give the my errordataresult as a result

Comment: @fubar I don’t think so. Because it works with double normally. But it just doesn’t work if I add the parameters on runtime. But I will try the one &

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

I should TMP_InputField instead TMP_Text.

It works.